# Why I can NOT redirect standard output/error to log in Linux

Tags: linux, git, bash

I try to redirect both the standard output and error of a simple Linux command as below :

```
git clone https://git.oschina.net/luzhao/helloworld.git  &> log
```

after it finish I look into the log file :

```
cat log
Cloning into 'helloworld'...
```

absolutely , the log is not completed , some output was missed somehow . The completed log should be like this :

```
git clone https://git.oschina.net/luzhao/helloworld.git         
Cloning into 'helloworld'...
remote: Counting objects: 18, done.
remote: Compressing objects: 100% (7/7), done.
remote: Total 18 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
Unpacking objects: 100% (18/18), done.
Checking connectivity... done.
```

anyone can help ? why some output were missed ? I am using Ubuntu14.04 with bash

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a weirdness of git, [the output changes when it's not being sent to a terminal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4062862/git-stderr-output-cant-pipe). Pass the `--progress` option to git.